# Google News APIを利用する際の利用規約について

Tags: api, google-cloud, google-api

Google News API利用規約に関しての質問がございます。
詳細は下記の通りとなります。

■概要
現在、担当しているPJにおいて、某企業向けにSalesforceを用いてシステム導入を実施しております。当システムでは、無料公開されているGoogle News API にて、システム上の顧客名に基づくGoogle Newsを画面上に表示させようとしております。
昨日、G Suiteサポートへ同内容の問合せを実施したところ、Google　Newsの問合せ窓口はなく、本内容はStack Overflowへ確認してくださいとの回答をいただきました。

■質問事項
下記AP利用内容について利用規約に反する利用方法となっていないか契約/課金の要否を確認させていただきたく。また本件の正確なサポート窓口がわかる方がおりましたら、ご教示頂けましたら幸いです。

■詳細
【利用API】
https://urldefense.proofpoint.com/v2/url?u=https-3A__news.google.com_news_rss_search_section_q_&d=DwIGaQ&c=eIGjsITfXP_y-DLLX0uEHXJvU8nOHrUK8IrwNKOtkVU&r=NyS8aYjcJDbJd75r6wuVI-VWYxGOJS-fWk2e6ncH9Vw&m=S_dQPyZ5aBlAwB4FrZ5AJN1DDiPdl3vpNtz25mj39Dg&s=NTw18kf1tcKnGf7YMiapklzFHGBkFvHr5OwxplqMa6U&e

【API利用方法】
顧客システム画面の横にGoggle Newsを表示。画面表示時にSalesforce ApexよりNews/RSS情報を取得、バッチ起動等による機械的なコールはなく、画面表示イベント時のみAPIコールでの利用を想定。

【利用者】システム導入先 社員のみ/社内システム

【確認済の使用許諾情報】
https://urldefense.proofpoint.com/v2/url?u=https-3A__www.google.com_intl_ja-5Fjp_terms-5Fgoogle-5Fnews.html&d=DwIGaQ&c=eIGjsITfXP_y-DLLX0uEHXJvU8nOHrUK8IrwNKOtkVU&r=NyS8aYjcJDbJd75r6wuVI-VWYxGOJS-fWk2e6ncH9Vw&m=S_dQPyZ5aBlAwB4FrZ5AJN1DDiPdl3vpNtz25mj39Dg&s=S9u4a9NW-Skb3aVTb6_FRJJAop-CloQHDvaxndLLqvg&e

上記について、ご回答いただけましたら幸いです。
以上、よろしくお願いいたします。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Google News API`ですが、[質問記載の使用許諾情報](https://www.google.com/intl/ja_jp/terms_google_news.html)は、`Google News`のものであって、`Google News API`には適用されないと思います。

なぜかというと、「質問記載の使用許諾情報」は、一般的なもので、コンテンツには著作権があるから、著作権で認められている個人使用を除いては「コピー、転載、改変、変更、および派生物の作成」は駄目ということです。例えば、`Google News`をスクレーピングして、社内用のシステムを作成することは使用許諾違反になります。（余談ですが、`Google News`はそもそもGoogleがスクレーピングして作成しているものなので、データベースとしての著作権はあると思うのですが、少量のスクレーピングをして社内に流すことが本当に違法行為になるのかについては疑問があります。ただし、使用許諾違反としてサービスを止めることは可能です。）

一方、`API`は、そもそもシステムで利用して公開することを前提として作られています。公開されている`API`を使って社内システムを作っても、`API`の利用規約の方で明示的に禁止されていなければ問題になることはないと思われます。

`Google News`に関して使える`API`には、２種類あります。`Google News Search API`と`RSS`です。`Google News Search API`は、2011年5月26日にDeprecate（廃止予定）になっていますが、現在も利用制限はありますが使えています。`RSS`の方も利用はできるようですが、`Google News`の画面からは消えています。

Googleのサービスで廃止予定になって7年も続けているサービスもは珍しいです。`Google News`の`API`は、便利な機能ですよね。それで使っている人が多いので廃止せずに続けているのだと思います。こういうケースでは、サポート窓口はなく、契約/課金については明確に回答がなされないと思われます。いつ「廃止」されるかわからないサービスだし、使いすぎると止められることも考えておく必要があります。

Comment: ＠Yasuhiro Nijiさん
本件、ご丁寧な回答、誠にありがとうございました。
廃止予定になっても7年以上も続けられている背景があって、サポート窓口がなかったのですね。
回答いただいた内容を踏まえて、方針を検討していきたいと思います。ありがとうございました。